# Unable to set "Session" variable MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, session, razor-pages

In my controller I pass a model to view

```
public IActionResult Forgotpassword()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionString"] = "sample";

    Forgotpasswordinfo Vmodel = new Forgotpasswordinfo();
    return View(Vmodel);
}
```

I use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionString"] = "sample";`  to make a session variable but it shows an error saying HttpContext does not exist!? What am I missing?

Comment: how do i access that in my view? im trying @session["something"] but session doesnt exist

Comment: HttpContext doesnt exist in my view thats the issue i did set a session variable in my controller just like how said and it worked now in my view i want to check the value of that session variable

Comment: where is your view code? I don't see it posted. In your controller view (.cshtml), you use the property `Context` (not `HttpContext` as in controller or Razor page).

Comment: `string s; s = Context.Session.TryGetValue("Isvalid", out s); if (s == true) { }` thats my view if Isvalid is true then i show a panel to the user if not ill do something else is that correct now?

Comment: my bad, looks like Session in asp.net core is a big difference from the old asp.net. You cannot use dictionary-style syntax when setting/getting the value. The stored value type is `byte[]` but can be serialized from other data type (usually string). For complex type, you store the JSON instead. There are only a few methods to store `string` & `int`, for other types you need custom extension methods, check it out here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2 So in your case you should store a `string` for the most convenience.

Comment: BTW, from what you commented, looks like the code above is in `asp.net mvc` (not `asp.net core`)? That's so confusing to tag both of them because the code between the 2 frameworks can be completely different, as in this case about using `Session`.

Comment: I thought they shared a lot in common in more basic stuff my bad. I have a “forgot my password” page where the user puts in their info. If the info matches the database i set a variable Isvidated true. If Isvalidated is true it’ll show a form where they can change their passowrd. So its two different forms on one single view that i want to switch between. Should i use Session variables for this or is there a better option

Comment: there are many strategies to handle password-forgotten scenario, usually requiring an `email`. But if your user has some other secure info to verify (so that you can base on that to allow him to reset the password), then right after submitting such info, you just need to return the View containing the reset-password form. But it requires a secure token generated from the last verification. Well it's fairly complicated for a beginner.

Comment: one simpler approach is you include new-password fields together with the secondary secure info form. So just one submission is required, if the verification is succeeded, you can reset the user's password right away (one submission, one round trip/request). It's simpler but may not be a very beautiful UX.

Comment: @iamaaarianme: Look at [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0). You should to use `Context.Session.GetString()/Context.Session.SetString()` to access a session parameters. But please, don't use ASP.NET MVC tag if you are talk about `ASP.NET Core`.

Comment: got it thanks! i have a question about the structure we pass info on. is it common to pass UserID in the url when the user successfully signs in? or should i just store that user id in a secured session and access it when needed through that ?

Comment: @Jackdaw thank you so much. my bad i thought they were pretty much the same MVC 5 and .Net Core

Comment: @iamaaarianme: Passing a UserID in the url is not secured...

Comment: whats the best way to keep that handy without passing it in the url?

Comment: @iamaaarianme: This is a different question. Please, don't stack all questions. Post a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how to set up the in-memory session provider:

```
public class Startup
{    
    //...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".TestApp.Session";                
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //...
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

`HttpContext.Session` can't be accessed before `UseSession` has been called.

Setting a variable in the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public IActionResult Index()
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Parameter", "bla bla");
    return View();
}
```

Obtain the parameter in the view *(Index.cshtml)*:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http; 
@{    
    string parameter = Context.Session.GetString("Parameter");
}
```

Mostly the code above is part of example from the Microsoft documentation. For the detailed information see [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0).